# How do I get recordtype in a loop?

Tags: apex, record-type, loop

I am getting Variable does not exist: recordType exception in for loop

```java
public void getGroupCallCustomers()
    {
        leftValues = new map<string,string>();
        rightValues = new map<string,string>();
        mapOfGrpCustomers = new map<string,string>();
        
        set<string> setOfCustomers = new set<string>();
        
        Map<String, String> currenPageParams = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
        
        for(Reference__c ref :[select id, Customer__c, Customer__r.name, Organisation__c, Organisation__r.name
                                from Reference__c where Organisation__c =: currenPageParams.get('org')])
        {
            setOfCustomers.add(ref.Customer__c);
        }
        
        system.debug('Target__r.MedRep__c : ' + userInfo.getUserId());
        system.debug('setOfCustomers : ' + setOfCustomers);
        system.debug('currenPageParams.get : ' + currenPageParams.get('con'));
        
        for(TF__c tf: [select id, Customer__c, Customer__r.name  from TF__c where
                        Target__r.MedRep__c =: userInfo.getUserId() AND Customer__c IN: setOfCustomers
                        AND Customer__c !=: currenPageParams.get('con') AND MC_In_Scope__c = 1])
        {
            leftValues.put(tf.Customer__c, tf.Customer__r.name);
            
        }
        
    }
        
    public List<SelectOption> getunSelectedValues()
    {
       
      
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
       
        for(string s : leftvalues.keyset()){
  
                if(leftvalues.recordType !='Administrator')
               options.add(new SelectOption(s,leftvalues.get(s)));
                
            
        }
        if(options.size()>0)
            haveGrpCustomers = true;
        
        return options;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### The short version:

You need to query for it, just like any other data.

#### The longer version:

RecordTypes are primarily used with SObjects, so if the thing you're trying to `.RecordType.Name` isn't an SObject you're going to have a bad time.

Your current `leftvalues`, being a `map<string, string>` will *never* have a record type associated with it (it's a map, not an `SObject`), and neither will the keys or values stored in the map (they're both currently strings, again, not an `SObject`)

So at the very least, you would need to make 3 changes here:

- Have your `leftvalues` map be a `Map<String, TF__c>` (so that it can store something that *can* have a RecordType)
- Explicitly add the record type into the `SELECT` clause of your query. E.g. add `RecordType.Name` or `Customer__r.RecordType.Name`, or something to that effect
- In the target for loop, iterate over `leftvalues.values()` instead of `leftvalues.keySet()`

  - There doesn't appear to be any reason to iterate over the map keys
    here
  - Further, there doesn't appear to be any reason to use a Map
    here instead of a List)
  - You'll want to change the loop variable to
    be of type `TF__c`, and then you'd be able to access the record type
    name inside of the loop using dot notation